# How to write to a stream after piping?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

In NodeJS I have this using ExpressJS (where `res` is a writable stream)

```
const readableStream = someAsyncTask();
readableStream.pipe(res);
readableStrean.on('end', () => {
    res.write('a bit more');
    res.end();
});
```

This is resulting in:

> uncaught exception Error: write after end

So I assume the pipe is causing the writable stream to close.  How can I pipe the readable stream to the output, and then when that stream ends, stream additional data to the output?

Comment: Damn that was kind of obvious, wasn't it.  Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable)

> **readable.pipe(destination[, options])**
>
> - *destination* `<stream.Writable>` The destination for writing data
> - *options*
>     `<Object>` Pipe options
>     *end* `<Boolean>` End the writer when the reader
>     ends. Defaults to true.
>     ...

If you don't want it to end when piping, pass `{end : false}` as options

```
readableStream.pipe(res, { end: false });
```